# Como adicionar funcionalidade nos botões

Tags: php, sql, bootstrap

eu sou novo com php, e estou fazendo um gerenciador de site, com ele quero manipulando o banco de dados, estou listando os dados do banco e cada item do banco tem três botões o de visualisar; Editar, que vai editar o nome e Apagar;
mas não sei como colocar função neles para alterar o item que estiver selecionado, mais especificamente eu não sei pegar o id do selecionado. Me ajudem este projeto e pra entregar dia 26/022018.

Comment: A sua pergunta está com um escopo muito grande. Pesquise sobre CRUD PHP e depois faça perguntas especificas.

Comment: Mostre o código que você já tem e tente explicar melhor qual é o problema

Comment: amigo muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu já entendi e já fiz, obrigado !